# Android: How to display animation with transparent BG?

Tags: android, flash, animation

I'd like to display a animation with transparent background, on a transparent activity. How can I realize it with Android? I thought about flash, but the user has to have flash installed, right? I'd prefer vector graphics instead of gifs.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Example:

[image]

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto I've tried animated Gifs, but I prefer vector graphics, to be able to resize the graphic without quality-loss and add custom texts to the animation (flash). 

Maybe it's not different than "any other animation", but I've no idea how to display "any other animation". Please tell me, what exactly you mean. I'm new to Android Development and thankful for every advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to show an animation is to store them as PNGs and do something like this for an animation, put this in your drawable folder.:

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="false"> 
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ant1" android:duration="100" /> 
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ant2" android:duration="100" /> 
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ant3" android:duration="100" /> 
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ant2" android:duration="100" /> 
</animation-list>
```

If you want to use vector graphics, then you have to manually switch the images. You could look into [svg-android](http://code.google.com/p/svg-android/), which is a great way to use simple vector images in Android.

Answer (score 1):

Hey you this library for animation of background image and set theme Theme.Transparent for activity...so you can achieve your requirement This is the link might be usefull...[KenBurnsView](https://github.com/flavienlaurent/NotBoringActionBar)